# Application Running with Wine Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: mac, applications, homebrew, wine

I am trying to run [Super Smash Land](http://www.supersmashland.com) using Wine on my Mac Book Pro (Mojave). I have installed Wine and XQuartz using Home-brew on my computer and ran the .exe file with `wine SuperSmashLand.exe`. While running it though, the graphics obviously is not displaying properly, with a large part of the apps appearing as gray (click link above to see how it should display). How can I fix this?

[image]
[image]

I have tried re-opening the application and changing the graphics setting of wine via `winecfg`, but nothing is working.

Comment: Please register and use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to regain access to your account, so that you'll be able to edit and respond to your question.